# How to fix Unmatched '{' in script with 6 functions for Datatable with childRows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to implement the child row feature to display extra columns fetched from a google spreadsheet into a basic Datable I've setup via a combination of Datatables, Tabletop and Bootstrap scripts packaged on github. This basic datatable is live and working fine error-free.

I've created a duplicate of the html page & the JS file and modified the code to implement the child rows according to the Datatable reference page. The html page is here: https://www.socialtheorywatch.org/database2.html
If you need to see the original basic working Datatable code just remove the `2` from the URL.

Google chrome browser console & JShint keep throwing Unmatched `{` on line 73 of my code `$(document).ready(function() {`. The full JShint error list looks like this:

> Four warnings 127 Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
>   127   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
>   expression. 73    Unmatched '{'. 128  Unrecoverable syntax error. (100%
>   scanned).

Before the syntax error issue I had the table drawn up fine with the open/close column successfully drawn, but the onClick function wasn't revealing the child rows. I posted that issue on the Datables forum and they helped me with moving the onClick function inside the bottom of the writeTable function by removing a closed curly bracket '}' from the line right before it. But now I get the syntax errors and I've fiddled with adding/removing/repositioning all sorts of brackets everywhere with no luck.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function initializeTabletopObject() {
    Tabletop.init({
      key: key,
      callback: function(data, tabletop) {
        writeTable(data); //call up datatables function
      },
      simpleSheet: true,
      debug: false });
  }

  initializeTabletopObject();

  function writeTable(data) {
    //select main div and put a table there
    //use bootstrap css to customize table style: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables
    $('#childRowTest').html(
      '<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" border="1" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-responsive" id="wrongfulConvictionDBSA"></table>'
    );

    //initialize the DataTable object and put settings in
    $("#wrongfulConvictionDBSA").DataTable({
      "autoWidth": false,
      "data": data,
      "columns": columns,
      "order": [
        [7, "desc"]
      ], //order on second column
      "pagingType": "simple_numbers" //'Previous' and 'Next' buttons, plus page numbers
      //"pageLength": 50
      //"lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ]
        //uncomment these options to simplify your table
        //"paging": false,
        //"searching": false,
        //"info": false
    });

  // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#wrongfulConvictionDBSA tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });  
});
//end of writeTable
```

I'm looking to resolve the syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of an answer to the "table not defined" issue described [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56307802/how-to-fix-unmatched-in-script-with-6-functions-for-datatable-with-childrows/56307875?noredirect=1#comment99226460_56307875), but it seemed somewhat clumsy and inappropriate to try to solve it in replies.

It looks like your code is based on [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

But in that example, the `table` variable is declared and assigned the return value of the `DataTable` call:

```js
  var table = $(...).DataTable({...})
```

and you're not doing that in your code:

```js
//initialize the DataTable object and put settings in
$("#wrongfulConvictionDBSA").DataTable({
  "autoWidth": false,
  "data": data,
   ...
```

There may be other problems, but I'd start by getting the `table` variable and then see what breaks next, if anything.

Comment: I have ```var columns``` outside and above the ```$(document).ready(function() {``` different from the Datables example. Modified accordingly to integrate Tabletop features with Datatables. Maybe I need to rework all that. I'll investigate after some time away from the computer and will report back.

Comment: Ok finally resolved between yours and Paul T's help (adding the extra closing curly bracket in between the last 2 sets of ```});``` at the end, and your guidance on focusing on the var issue, I also got help from the Datable forum to ultimately add ```var table =``` to the beginning of the  ```$("#wrongfulConvictionDBSA").DataTable({``` function. All good now!

Comment: Ha. You got help from the DataTable forum to do what the answer directly above this comment suggested?

Comment: Indeed you both gave the same answer but differently. I was able to copy paste the exact line of code needed without thinking about filling in the blanks. My scrambled brain (been fussing with this for 2 days) thanks all of you for your time and help.